# Rails acts_as_paranoid migration giving error on confirmation of devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, acts-as-paranoid, ruby-paranoia

```
class Advertiser < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:confirmable

acts_as_paranoid    
end
```

I added the Devise gem first without the confirmable option. Then I later added the confirmable option with this migration:

```
class AddConfirmableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration
def up
add_column :advertisers, :confirmation_token, :string
add_column :advertisers, :confirmed_at, :datetime
add_column :advertisers, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime

add_index :advertisers, :confirmation_token, :unique => true

Advertiser.update_all(:confirmed_at => Time.now)

end
end
```

When I run migration it gives an error

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column advertisers.deleted_at does not exist
LINE 1: ...onfirmed_at" = '2015-11-05 06:24:26.513079' WHERE "advertise...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the migration file like this:

```
class AddConfirmableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :advertisers, :confirmation_token, :string
    add_column :advertisers, :confirmed_at, :datetime
    add_column :advertisers, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
    add_index :advertisers, :confirmation_token, unique: true
    add_column :advertisers, :deleted_at, :time
    execute("UPDATE advertisers SET confirmed_at = NOW()")
  end

  def down
    remove_columns :advertisers, :confirmation_token, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_sent_at
  end 
end
```

For further reference see [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users)